# Is there a way to append html to web component?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, web-component

I've a custom js web component:

```
class MainDiv extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() { super(); }
  connectedCallback() {
   this.innerHTML = '<div id="mydiv"><input type="text" oninput="onInput(event)"/></div>'
  }
}
```

and in main.js I've the `function onInput*()`

```
function onInput(event) {
  const mainDiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
  const newLabel = document.createElement('span');
        newLabel.innerText = `${event.target.value.length}/255`; // output: 5/255...n/255
  mainDiv.appendChild(newLabel);
}
```

If I add a log in the `onInput` function it prints and does not return any error, but is not updating the webcomponent. Why?

Answer (score 0):

There must be something else at play, your code works:

```html
<script>
  function onInput(event) {
    const mainDiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    const newLabel = document.createElement('div');
    newLabel.innerText = `${event.target.value.length}/255`; // output: 5/255...n/255
    mainDiv.appendChild(newLabel);
  }
  customElements.define("my-element", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.innerHTML = '<div id="mydiv"><input type="text" oninput="onInput(event)"/></div>'
    }
  });

</script>
<my-element></my-element>
```

**Note**

```
 constructor() {
   super();
 }
```

Is not required, it says *run the constructor from my parent*, which is also done when you leave out the constructor in your Component.
Only when you do more in the constructor is it required.